# How do I sort the second column alphabetically and then by numbers in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a text file as below :

info.txt

```
files-550519470 19h
files-1662192679 1d
files-247106034 1d
files-1986982365 2d
files-464153317 12m
files-739420408 3d
files-77614277 3m
files-374059185 4d
files-909323637 4d
files-101830442 5d
files-1270496134 5d
files-1797797160 6d
files-812888216 7d
files-118869238 7h
```

I want to sort based on the second column alphabet and after that decreasing order of the number in the same second column and output should look like below :

```
 files-812888216 7d
 files-1797797160 6d
 files-101830442 5d
 files-101830442 5d
 files-1270496134 5d
 files-374059185 4d
 files-909323637 4d
 files-374059185 4d
 files-909323637 4d
 files-739420408 3d
 files-1986982365 2d
 files-1662192679 1d
 files-247106034 1d
 files-550519470 19h
 files-118869238 7h
 files-464153317 12m
 files-77614277 3m
```

I can reverse based on number by below command but can't figure out regarding alphabets . Can somebody please suggest ?

```
 sort -r -nk2 info.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Decorate, Sort, Undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) pattern:

```
$ sort -t $'-' -k 2 file | 
sed -E 's/(.*) ([[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*)([dmh]$)/\2 \3 \1 \2\3/' | 
awk 'BEGIN{arr["m"]=1; arr["h"]=60; arr["d"]=60*24}
     {$2=$1*arr[$2]; $1=""; print}' | 
sort -s -k1nr |
cut -d' ' -f3-
files-812888216 7d
files-1797797160 6d
files-101830442 5d
files-101830442 5d
files-1270496134 5d
files-374059185 4d
files-374059185 4d
files-909323637 4d
files-909323637 4d
files-739420408 3d
files-1986982365 2d
files-1662192679 1d
files-247106034 1d
files-550519470 19h
files-118869238 7h
files-464153317 12m
files-77614277 3m
```

This should be significantly faster than a Bash loop. It can be further optimized if you have `gawk` to replace `sort` and `sed`

---

If you have GNU or BSD sort, you can take advantage of alphabetically `d<h<m` and not do the conversion:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^-]*)-(.*) ([[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*)([dmh]$)/\2 \4 \3 \1-\2 \3\4/' file |
sort -s -t $' ' -k2,2 -k3,3nr -k1,1 |
cut -d $' ' -f4-
# same output
```

Answer (score 1):

@edit

Thank you @shelter for help! We can do it in just:

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \([0-9]*\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)/\3 \2 \1 \2\3/' |
sort -k1 -k2nr |
cut -d' ' -f3-
```

1. `sed` adds two new columns in front, one with the letter from the 3th column, the second column with the number from the 3th column
2. Then we sort using the first column and second column numerical reverse
3. Then we removed the extra added columns.

I leave the old answer as a reference.

This is my idea, it works, but definitely is not the best:

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \([0-9]*\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)/\3 \2 \1 \2\3/' |
sort -k1 | 
{
    presuffix=''
    buff=''
    while IFS=' ' read -r suffix rest; do
        if [ "$presuffix" != "$suffix" ]; then
            echo -n "$buff" | sort -n -r -k1 
            presuffix=$suffix
            buff=''
        fi
        buff+="$rest"$'\n'
    done
    printf "%s" "$buff" | sort -n -r -k1
} |
cut -d' ' -f2-
```

1. The sed get's the `1d` on the beginning of the line so the line is prepended with `d 1 ... rest of the line`. So the line is prepended with two new columns - one we want to sort alphabetically and the other we want to sort numerically.
2. Then we sort using the first column (alphabet).
3. Then I split the stream into separate parts using buffer and reverse sort each part using the second field (number) (the first field get's removed in the `while read` so it's first column now).
4. Then the `cut -d' ' -f2-` removed the first column (number).
5. This will be slow because of the `while read` part, but I have no better idea.

@edit:

Another solution really under the influence of @shelter comment.

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \([0-9]*\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)/\3 \2 \1 \2\3/' |
while IFS=' ' read -r suffix num rest; do
    echo "$(printf "%d * 256 + (256 - %d)\n" "'$suffix" "$num" | bc)" "$rest"
done |
sort -r -n |
cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Assuming there is only a single character suffix in the sorted column (`1d` or `1e` or `1h` or `19d`) and the numbers in the sorted column are smaller then 256 (magic number, may be increased), we can convert the character into ascii number.

Then we can multiply the ascii number by 256 and to it add the number within the sorted column. The number is substracted with 256, cause within each chunk we want to reverse sort using numbers (`7d` is first, `1d` then). Then we just numerically sort it.

We could alternatively use `printf "(256 - %d) + %d"` and then reverse numericall sort, the difference is only when two fields are equal (ex. in case of `files-1662192679` and `files-247106034`).

The magic number `256` should be greater then the the biggest number in the sorted column and also greater then the biggest ascii representation of the character in the sorted column. Probably this could be extended to handle multiple characters in the sorted column.

Comment: You're on the right track, but why not just convert `n days = n * 24 * 60 ; h hours = h * 60, ;... etc` and insert that value as the first column (leaving last column in place),  pipe to sort, pipe to awk again and remove first column.

Comment: If I convert them to integers, then the reverse sort will break. The thinkg is, chars need to be sorted alphabetically `d` > `h`  > `m`. But hours duration is smaller then days duration (don't know how to say it). The result should be: days first, then hours, then months. And the numbers within days should be reverse sorted. I think, knowing for each line `n < 100` we could `d days = n * 100**2 ; h = h * 100 ; m months = n` then sort numerically.

Comment: First off, do the time expansion to minutes w `awk` at the front of the pipeline. I'm thinking that the output of that would look like `1140 files-550519470 19h`. Now you can sort records numerically (and reversed) by the first field. So you have `awk '{mins=cvrtToMins($NF); print mins "\t" $0}' inputFile | sort ....| awk '{$1=""}'` Sorry I wasn't clearer before. Good luck to all.

Comment: Ah, missed your `|cut -d...` That works too ;-) (and note that `1d = 1440 mins`). Of course the O.P. will now query now to deal with `3d 5h 7m` And related to your use of `256 - %d` etc, there are numerous solutions in `awk` to solve "converting" `1d` to just `1` and then `1440 (mins)`. You can usually get away with just an assignment `m=($NF+0)` will strip out any chars in the specified field. Good luck!

Comment: @Kamil Cuk Thanks for your response . What I did now was to split the 2nd column as alphabet and digits separate and made 3 columns . I am doing sort after that .    `sort -k3 info.txt` sorted it alphabetically . but how do I sort it numerically that I get the above ouput ? what can I use to sort primarily on 3rd column and secondary on 2nd column(reverse in 2nd col)

Comment: You can't. The think is `sort` will sort both columns reverse or both columns normal. You need to split that into parts and reverse sort the parts... See my answer... I take the alphetically sorted and then create parts which i store into `buf` which then are feeded into `sort -r` each part after another.

Comment: @KamilCuk : You need to learn how to read `man` pages (and sort is very complicated).;-). Each field specified as a sort column can be further modified with a range of modifiers. `sort -k3 -k2nr file` sorts firstly (primarily) on the 3rd column and then on the 2nd column, numerically and reverse. Good luck to all!

Comment: Och, I never could understand that 'KEYDEF' part from sort manpage, was always stuck with it! Thanks!

Comment: Your `sed | sort | cut` pipeline does not produce the example result. You can come *close* by changing the `sort` command to `sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr -k3,3` but that will only work if the prefix is all the same `files-`